# A remark on the abc conjecture

Tags: discussion, on-topic, comments

It went/goes something like this:

"It [the *abc* conjecture] resembles a false proposition in that A GREAT DEAL of results would follow from its veracity".

I may have read it in the comments of a discussion on [Mochizuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinichi_Mochizuki)'s papers on IUT sometime in 2012; the thing is that I don't recall if it was on MO or on a blog post (maybe one by J. Ellenberg?) mentioned in actual MO thread.

Does any of you remember reading this witty remark once? If so, could you please tell me where I can find it?

Let me thank you in advance for your attention and support.

*Fukugen*.

Comment: Why post this at meta and not at MO? Meta is for discussing how the MO site works, its policies, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the remark you want is on [page 361](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=ZOfUsvemJDMC&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=abc%20conjecture%20false) of the Princeton Companion to Mathematics.

Edit in response to a comment - the paragraph in question follows:

> The ABC conjecture has many other marvelous consequences; for a delightful survey, see Granville and Tucker (2002).  In fact the ABC conjecture and its generalizations can be used to prove so many things that I have joked that it is beginning to resemble a false statement, since a false statement implies everything.  But probably the ABC conjecture is true.  Indeed, though a bit harder to see, the Erdős-Ulam probabilistic argument can be modified to provide heuristic evidence for it, too.

Comment: Yes, this is just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: It would be good if you write down what it is....

Comment: Hello, thanks for edit.. When I first clicked on that link which says page 361, it did not show any thing.. That is why I asked... Now it is showing correctly... May be I went to next page and did not realize so I saw some blank page in with some note written in Chinese..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sorry, I had linked to the Japanese (not Chinese) Google Books site.

Comment: The selection of pages that are and are not shown in google books seems unpredictable. Today I was not able to see the quote, but I was able to see the author. Tomorrow, or for someone else, this may be different so I will record the author's name here: Carl Pomerance.